# "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

My code here returns the error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." and  I already added the code "MultipleActiveResultSets=true" on my web.config

```
        ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

        var sqlConnection = new SQLConnectionStrings();
        var conReport = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection.strConn);
        var cmdReport = new SqlCommand();
        var myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmdReport;

        SqlDataReader drReport;

        DataSet dsReport = new DataSet();
        //PerfLogDataSet();


        cmdReport.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdReport.Connection = conReport;
        conReport.Open();
        cmdReport.CommandText = baseQuery;
        drReport = cmdReport.ExecuteReader();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(dsReport); //where the error occurs
        dsReport.Tables[0].Load(drReport);
        drReport.Close();
        conReport.Close();
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `dsReport.Tables[0].Load(drReport);` You have already loaded that table with the Fill. And that's the same for the ExecuteReader before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to simultaneously use a `SqlDataAdapter` and `SqlDataReader` with the same `SqlCommand`.

`SqlDataAdapter` will load the result set into a `DataSet` or `DataTable`.  `SqlDataReader` is for looping over the result set one record at a time, recordset-style.  They are two different methods for accessing data with two different intents, and it makes no sense to use both.

If you're trying to load `dsReport`, get rid of

```
SqlDataReader drReport;
drReport = cmdReport.ExecuteReader();
dsReport.Tables[0].Load(drReport);
drReport.Close();
```

As you are already loading it with the adapter using

```
myDataAdapter.Fill(dsReport);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code if you want to fill dataset...

```
    ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

    var sqlConnection = new SQLConnectionStrings();
    var conReport = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection.strConn);
    var cmdReport = new SqlCommand(baseQuery);
    var myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdReport,sqlConnection );

    DataSet dsReport = new DataSet();

    conReport.Open();
    myDataAdapter.Fill(dsReport);
    conReport.Close();
```

but if you want anything else ,describe it ,more ;)